# Detecting unexpected socket disconnect

Tags: c#, sockets

This is not a question about how to do this, but a question about whether it's wrong what I'm doing. I've read that it's not possible to detect if a socket is closed unexpectedly (like killing the server/client process, pulling the network cable) while waiting for data (BeginReceive), without use of timers or regular sent messages, etc. But for quite a while I've been using the following setup to do this, and so far it has always worked perfectly.

```
public void OnReceive(IAsyncResult result)
{
    try
    {
        var bytesReceived = this.Socket.EndReceive(result);

        if (bytesReceived <= 0)
        {
            // normal disconnect
            return;
        }

        // ...

        this.Socket.BeginReceive...;
    }
    catch // SocketException
    {
        // abnormal disconnect
    }
}
```

Now, since I've read it's not easily possible, I'm wondering if there's something wrong with my method. Is there? Or is there a difference between killing processes and pulling cables and similar?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's perfectly possible and OK to do this. The general idea is:

**If `EndReceive` returns anything other than zero**, you have incoming data to process.

**If `EndReceive` returns zero**, the remote host has closed its end of the connection. That means it can still receive data you send if it's programmed to do so, but cannot send any more of its own under any circumstances. Usually when this happens you will also close your end the connection thus completing an orderly shutdown, but that's not mandatory.

**If `EndReceive` throws**, there has been an abnormal termination of the connection (process killed, network cable cut, power lost, etc).

A couple of points you have to pay attention to:

1. `EndReceive` can never return less than zero (the test in your code is misleading).
2. If it throws it can throw other types of exception in addition to `SocketException`.
3. If it returns zero you must be careful to stop calling `BeginReceive`; otherwise you will begin an infinite and meaningless ping-pong game between `BeginReceive` and `EndReceive` (it will show in your CPU usage). Your code already does this, so no need to change anything.

Comment: +1 in particular because I like how you put "if it's programmed to do so".

Comment: +1 I would also like to point out that you should never have a catch statement that catches everything unless it re-throws it.

Comment: @Alex I disagree with the prohibition of catching all exceptions unless you rethrow them.

I have a TCP-server class, that works very much like the one here and I don't want some random exception to terminate the whole server application.

That is why I catch all Exceptions and pass them to an OnExceptionCaught Event-Handler, which should be connected to some logging functionality etc.

Comment: Exceptions which aren't caught in the Receive-Callback (like here), go through to the Thread from the Threadpool - that's the end of the first-chance exception, so Visual Studio halts the application with a message "Exception was not handled by user code". This only happens when you run the program in visual studio and you can resume running, but unless you have an event-handler for AppDomain.UnhandledException, the application is terminated. IMHO that's not what this event is for. AppDomain.UnhandledException is more like a last resort for writing a stack-trace for post-mortem debugging....